# Media player's setnextmediaplayer for api level <16

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using MediaPlayer for music playback in my android application. My app is supported on all Api levels >8. I need to use the function setNextMediaPlayer to achieve gapless looping. I tried going to the grep files and understanding the code for this method, but found out this was a native method.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#MediaPlayer

How do I use this function for API levels less than 16.

Comment: late to the party, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918930/setnextmediaplayer-not-working) could be helpful to future comers

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve looping, you can do this on media player instance

```
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Proper implementation

```
Mediaplayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setDataSource(context, your_media_url);
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.prepare();

mPlayer.setLooping(true);

mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but this method has gaps in the looping. I need gapless looping.

Comment: This is the best shot you have, Try using Exoplayer, hope it will solve your problem..