# setNextMediaPlayer not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to find out how to use the android's MediaPlayer method setNextMediaPlayer which should smoothly transition from one player (song) to another. But do not know how to use the method since there is a lack of documentation.

This is what i do and it does not work:

```
final MediaPlayer mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
    final MediaPlayer mp2 = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp1.setDataSource("http://song1.MP3");
        mp2.setDataSource("http://song2.mp3");


        mp1.prepareAsync();

        mp1.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp1.start();
            }
        });


        mp1.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);

        mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp2.prepareAsync();
                mp2.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp2.start();
                    }
                });


            }
        });

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
```

So the first song plays. But after it finishes the second does not start.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work.

```
mp1.setDataSource(song1);

        mp1.prepareAsync();

        mp1.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp1.start();
            }
        });
        //mp1.start();
        //mp1.seekTo(1000*100);

        mp2.setDataSource(song2);
        mp2.prepare();

        mp1.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);
```

The only problem is that the second mediaplayer cannot be called as async (i.e. mp2.prepareAsync()). I do not know why, but if you try it like that it does not start, which is a bad thing :/.

Answer (score -1):

MediaPlayer setNextMediaPlayer gives a lot of problem what i do is this:
in the onCompletion() reset() the mediaplayer, setDataSource() and prepareAsync().

Something like this

```
        mp1.setDataSource("http://song1.MP3");
        mp1.prepareAsync();
        mp1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp1.start();
            }
        });
        mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp1.reset();
                //ADD FLAG FOR STOP
                try {
                    mp1.setDataSource("http://song2.mp3");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mp1.prepareAsync();
            }
        });
```

Then in the onCompletion you need some flag to check if the last song was played to stop, because the code as i posted will loop in the last song.

Comment: Hi ismael, thanks for the answer, but you did not use the setNextMediaPlayer method? I am curious how to use it, since i know how to do it this way, but this way there is no smooth transition... The setNextMediPlayer method is intereseting because the documenatation says Set the MediaPlayer to start when this MediaPlayer finishes playback (i.e. reaches the end of the stream). The media framework will attempt to transition from this player to the next as seamlessly as possible.

Comment: no, i couldn't use setNextMediaPlayer  because the error for me was a broken pipe in some devices

Comment: ok... well, i have it already done like you proposed, but this is not what i am looking for since there is no smooth transition, like the one mentioned by the setNextMediaPlayer